# How do I place output of bash command to Python variable?

Tags: python

How do I place output of bash command to Python variable?

I am writing a Python script, which I want to enter the output of
bash command:
`rpm -qa --qf '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH} %{VENDOR}\n' | grep -v 'Red Hat'|wc -l`, and place it to Python variable, let say `R`.

After that I want to do, Python `if R != 0`
then run some Linux command.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Do you really need to go through a python script. Maybe jsut bash is sufficient. Your question is not very clear, could you add some more details about your python script.

Answer (score 2):

There are various options, but the easiest is probably using `subprocess.check_output()` with `shell=True` although this can be security hazard if you don't fully control what command is passed in.

```
import subprocess
var = subprocess.check_output('rpm -qa --qf '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH} %{VENDOR}\n' | grep -v 'Red Hat'|wc -l', shell = True)
var = int(var)
```

You need to use `shell=True` as otherwise the pipes would not be interpreted.

If you need more control you might want to look at [`plumbum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plumbum) where you can do:

```
from plumbum.cmd import rpm, grep, wc

chain = rpm["-qa", "--qf", r"%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH} %{VENDOR}\n"] | grep["-v", "Red Hat"] | wc["-l"]
R = int(chain())
```

Although I would probably not invoke `wc` and get the whole output and count its length within python (easier to check that you got just the lines that you expected, piping through `wc -l` throws away all of the details)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `envoy` primarily because the API is much more intuitive to use for 90% of the use cases.

```
r = envoy.run('ls ', data='data to pipe in', timeout=2)
print r.status_code  # returns status code
print r.std_out  # returns the output.
```

See the [Envoy Github](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy) page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stdin.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import  sys

s = sys.stdin.read()
print s
```

Then you will run a bash command like this

```
 echo "Hello" | ./myscript.py
```

Output

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [replace shell pipeline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) using Popen:

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen

p1 = Popen(["rpm", "-qa", "--qf", '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH} %{VENDOR}\n'],stdout=PIPE)

p2 = Popen(["grep", "-v", 'Red Hat'],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()

p3 = Popen(["wc", "-l"],stdin=p2.stdout,stdout=PIPE)
p2.stdout.close()
out,err = p3.communicate()
```

If you just want to check if grep returned any matches then forget the wc - l and just check what grep returns:

```
p1 = Popen(["rpm", "-qa", "--qf", '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH} %{VENDOR}\n'],stdout=PIPE)

p2 = Popen(["grep", "-v", 'Red Hat'],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
out,err = p2.communicate()
if out:
   ...
```

Or just use `check_output` to run the `rpm` command and check the string for `"Red Hat"`:

```
out = check_output(["rpm", "-qa", "--qf", '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH} %{VENDOR}\n'])

if "Red Hat" not in out:
    ....
```

Which is the same as inverting the search with `grep -v` then checking if there are any matches with wc.